# Tire Diameter Vs Tire Wear

Tags: tires

I was told that larger diameter tires, in my case 55/R19 , wear faster than a comparable smaller diameter, say 55/R17 inch tires.  Fact or fiction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't see any reason why that would be the case. In fact, on a purely theoretical basis, it ought to be the other way round, as a larger tyre would travel further per revolution (as it has a larger circumference), and so would go through less revolutions for a given distance, thus putting less friction on each square inch of rubber per mile.

In reality though, it doesn't make any difference. Compound, weather, road conditions, driving style, etc will affect the wear rate, but I don't think size will, if all other conditions are equal.

Comment: agreed - from experience of going through 2 or 3 sets a year, these are the major factors (in fact the top two for me are driving style and compound)